# Braintree iOS Drop-In with Paypal doesn't work

Tags: ios, paypal, braintree

I implemented the Braintree Drop In with Credit Card Payment into my iOS ( V. 10+ ) application. It works great. Now I wanted to add Paypal so I did the following:

Added Paypal to my pods:

*pod 'Braintree/PayPal'*

Added BTAppSwitch to my App Delegate like this:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4#update-your-application-delegate

Added my bundle identifier with .payments to info.plist whitelist.

Connected my Paypal sandbox account with my Braintree account.

When I run the app in the simulator or on my iOS device Paypal shows up in the Drop-In. But when I click on it, I get the following error message:

**The operation couldn’t be completed. client error**

I don't get any further error code. That's basically it.

The weird thing is, that before that happened, I needed to add the following URL to my info.plist whitelist, even though I haven't got Vemno installed / activated:

*com.venmo.touch.v2*

If I type in my app bundle identifier into Safari with ://test then my app shows up. So that works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be worth reaching out to [Braintree's Support Team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact). This often has to do with your actual account setup, rather than any code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It seems that it doesn't work with a PREMIER - kind-of-type. Had to link the Braintree Sandbox to a Paypal Sandbox App which is connected to a BUSINESS account.